# Android supporting more than one api

Tags: android, api

Im trying to figure out how to allow my app in dev which was initially started for 3.2 and up, to be backwards compatible with API v10 and up. I tried changing the API version in the project settings, but it doesnt hold. Could it be because I primarily use the Holo theme?

Comment: `but it doesnt hold`... Could you provide some more details? Compilation errors, warnings, symptoms etc.

Comment: have you changed it all in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line in your manifest.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

From what you said it sounds like you already went into properties>Android and changed your Project Build Target.  If not do so and change it to 10 also.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors:If you are using API specific features which are only available in API Level 11 and above , it cannot be backward compatible.
For it to be backward compatible use API which is available in that version, make the build target as that version and also set the minSdkVersion